# ZSH print '%' automatically after the result of the C program

Tags: c, vim, zsh

This is a simple C program:

[image: this is a simple C program]

This is the result of that program -- note the `%` at the end.

[image: this is the result of the C program , but here is the '%' at the end .]

Comment: The inverse `%` printed by zsh marks the place where the program exited without terminating the last output line. You should always terminate your lines with `\n`.

Comment: BTW, we ask that code be given as text, not screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122). Content that is only behind a link (even an image link!) is not considered "included in the question itself" for purposes of the rules at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (see in particularly #1 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list, calling for questions to include a [mcve]). Code only in a screenshot can't be copied-and-pasted for someone to see the problem themselves or test a fix.

Comment: See [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582)

Answer (score 5):

zsh prints a `%` (by default for a normal user) when the last line does not end with a newline character. This partial line could be erased by the prompt otherwise. Add a newline to properly terminate the last line (`\n`):

```
printf("1\n");
```

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSP

Comment: yeah thank you . Btw , may I just remove the '%'